# Why the integer part function doesn't have primitive?

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen that it's because that function doesn't satisfy the lagrange's mean value theorem, but I don't understand how that can answer my question.

Comment: A primitive (or antiderivative) $F$ of a function $f$ is a function that has the property that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of the functions.  Suppose that $F'(x)$ is the integer part of $x$.  What is the derivative of $F$ at 1?

Comment: There are two famous properties a derivative must possess: the intermediate value property and no jump discontinuity. The greatest integer function does not possess any of these properties so it can not be the derivative of any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it did have a primitive $F$, then $F'=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $F'= 1$ on $[1,2)$. So $F = c_1$ ( constant) on $[0,1]$ and $F=x+c_2$ on $[1,2]$. But then the left derivative at $1$ would be $0$, and the right derivative at $1$ would be $1$, so $F$ would not have a derivative at $1$.